# Style Facebook share button link

Tags: css, facebook, button, hyperlink, share

I'm wondering if it's possible to style the share button link. Here's the link I would like to access (nested in Facebook's iframe).

```
<a class="pluginShareButtonLink" href="/sharer.php?
app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;sdk=joey&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;
display=popup" target="_blank" id="u_0_1"><div class="blueButton blue"><div 
class="pluginButton"><div><div class="pluginButtonContainer"><div 
class="pluginButtonImage"><button type="submit"><i class="pluginButtonIcon img sp_25oo7a 
sx_e52148"></i></button></div><span class="pluginButtonLabel">Share</span></div></div>
</div></div></a>
```

I've tried to change the style of the class pluginShareButtonLink as follows:

```
.pluginShareButtonLink:hover{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

And it's not working. I've also tried to change the style with jQuery but this didn't work either. Can it be done somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
   **You can style the button with this css and you can change the background color to any color you want.**

    solution 1 (without gradient background color)
    .pluginButtonContainer button{ 
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 35px;
    background: rgb(255, 70, 70);
    border: 0px!important;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }

    solution 2 (with gradient background color)
    .pluginButtonContainer button{ 
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #ff3a3a; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff3a3a 0%, #ff3a3a 49%, #ff402b 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3a3a), color-stop(49%,#ff3a3a), color-stop(100%,#ff402b)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff3a3a 0%,#ff3a3a 49%,#ff402b 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ff3a3a 0%,#ff3a3a 49%,#ff402b 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ff3a3a 0%,#ff3a3a 49%,#ff402b 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ff3a3a 0%,#ff3a3a 49%,#ff402b 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3a3a', endColorstr='#ff402b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border: 0px!important;
    border-radius: 2px;
    }
```